# Override an ASCX control method in parent page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, overriding

I have an ASCX user control that is being used in about 60 web forms pages.  This control basically renders a series of nested drop down lists.

Inside the control, the method for populating the final list is like this:

```
Public Sub PopulateList()
   Dim dt as DataTable = MyDAL.GetListValues()
   For each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows
      Dim li as new ListItem
      ' ... 
      myDDL.Items.Add(li)
   Next
End Sub
```

In a small handful of pages, I need this method to work slightly differently (the list items are populated with more details, from a different table).

Is it possible somehow for the parent page of the control to somehow *override* the method?  I read about Overriding on various MSDN pages, but can't figure this out.  I can declare the method as...

```
 Public Overridable Sub PopulateList()
```

... but then in VS2015, when I try to create an overriding method using `Public Overrides` the Intellisense menu does not contain any reference to the user control, or the method.  I assume that this is because the control isn't actually being inherited by the page?

Is this possible to do, or is there another way please?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "override" the method in the parent page, because the page does not inherit from your control's class.

You could possibly create an event handler, or pass in a delegate to modify the behavior of the method.

For example:

```
Public Class Test1

    Dim t2 As New Test2

    Sub New()

        ' Call populateList with an action handler
        t2.PopulateList(Sub(ddl)
                        ' Do your logic here

                        Dim dt As DataTable = MyDAL.GetListValues()
                        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                            Dim li As New ListItem
                            ' ... 
                            ddl.Items.Add(li)
                        Next

                    End Sub)

    End Sub


End Class

Public Class Test2
    Public Sub PopulateList(Optional handler As Action(Of DropDownList) = Nothing)

        If handler Is Nothing Then
            ' Default behavior
            Dim dt As DataTable = MyDAL.GetListValues()
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Dim li As New ListItem
                ' ... 
                myDDL.Items.Add(li)
            Next

        Else

            ' Invoke action handler and pass a reference to the dropdown you want to add items to
            handler(myDDL)

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Example using an event:

```
Event MyCustomEvent As EventHandler(Of MyCustomEventArgs)

Public Sub PopulateList()

    Dim args As New MyCustomEventArgs()
    args.ListObject = myDDL
    RaiseEvent MyCustomEvent(Me, args)

    ' Do default behavior if not handled by event code
    If Not args.Handled Then

        Dim dt As DataTable = MyDAL.GetListValues()
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim li As New ListItem
            ' ... 
            myDDL.Items.Add(li)
        Next

    End If


End Sub
```

Custom event args class:

```
Public Class MyCustomEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Handled As Boolean
    Public Property ListObject As DropDownList
End Class
```

Handled on your page:

```
Protected Sub MyControl_MyCustomEvent(sender As Object, e As MyCustomEventArgs) Handles MyControl.MyCustomEvent

    e.Handled = True

    ' Do work on your list
    Dim mylist = e.ListObject


End Sub
```

Comment: That's interesting thank you.  I wasn't aware this could be done.  The only issue is that `PopulateList` is called internally in the control, so I would have to allow the list to be populated, then manually call it again from the Page (I *think*) to replace the ListItems with the new ones.

Comment: In that case, create a property and set that property in your page somewhere in the lifecycle (init maybe) before your control calls PopulateList. Then your PopulateList method would just use the property, instead of a parameter. But you would have to ensure it's set before PopulateList is called.

Comment: Or, as I mentioned in my post, you can use an Event. Raise an event to get the datasource you need and anything else required to build your custom list. I'll update my answer with an example shortly

Comment: I've added an example on how you could do it with an event. You simply define the event on your page, and your control will raise it when it's ready.

Comment: Aha... the Event approach looks very promising.  If I raise an event using the DropDownList as an argument `RaiseEvent SkillsListPopulated(Me.myDDL)`  then the page can interject the logic and replace the ListItems.  I thought this was an unnecessary step at first, but the `ListItem.Value`s can then be used by the page to quickly find the appropriate database replacements and push them back into the control.  I don't think I actually need `MyCustomEventArgs` although its useful to see how that works. :-)